# Passing data of select input between controller inangular

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem when I want passing data of select input between controllers

I can do with input (text or similar) but i don´t know with input like selects, checkbox and radio box...

How can I get the select data in the second controller?

Here an simple example

Thanks!

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("ExampleOneController", function($scope, NewsService) {

  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});
myApp.controller("ExampleTwoController", function($scope, NewsService) {

  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});

myApp.service("NewsService", function() {
  return {
    news: [{
      theme: "This is one new"
    }, {
      theme: "This is two new"
    }, {
      theme: "This is three new"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h2>
  ExampleOneController
  </h2>
  <select ng-options="item as item.theme for item in news track by item.theme" ng-model="data.singleSelect"></select>
   singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect.theme}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h2>
  ExampleTwoController
  </h2>
    <h2>
   singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect.theme}}
    </h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution, here can see a simple example of passing data between controllers ;)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('myService', function(){
    this.selected = {
        item: 'A' // I want this to return the currently selected value - If val is changed to 'B', update the text input accordingly.
    }
});
myApp.service('NewsService', function(){
  return {
    news: [{
      theme: "This is one new"
    }, {
      theme: "This is two new"
    }, {
      theme: "This is three new"
    }]
    }
});

myApp.controller('AController', ['$scope', 'myService','NewsService', function($scope, myService, NewsService){
    $scope.selected = myService.selected;
    $scope.news = NewsService.news;
}]);

myApp.controller('BController', ['$scope', 'myService','NewsService', function($scope, myService,NewsService){
    $scope.mySelected = myService.selected;
    $scope.myNews = NewsService.news;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="AController">
<h1>
controlador 1
</h1>
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="selected.item">
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
    </select>  
    <select ng-options="item as item.theme for item in news track by item.theme" ng-model="news.item"></select>
</div>
    
<div ng-controller="BController">
<h1>
controlador 2
</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mySelected.item">
    {{mySelected.item}}
      {{myNews.item}}
       {{myNews.item.theme}}
       <br>
       <select ng-options="item as item.theme for item in myNews track by item.theme" ng-model="myNews.item"></select>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By encapsulating `<div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">` inside `<div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">`.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("ExampleOneController", function($scope, NewsService) {
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});
myApp.controller("ExampleTwoController", function($scope, NewsService) {
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});

myApp.service("NewsService", function() {
  return {
news: [{
  theme: "This is one new"
}, {
  theme: "This is two new"
}, {
  theme: "This is three new"
}]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
<h2>ExampleOneController</h2>
<select ng-options="item as item.theme for item in news track by item.theme" ng-model="data.singleSelect"></select>

singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect.theme}}
  
<div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
 <h2>ExampleTwoController</h2>
 <h2>singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect.theme}}</h2>
</div>

  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, yes, it is a solution, but I need with separated controllers, for example if I have two different pages ;)

Comment: Then this approach is not possible. Use a `service` to share data between controllers. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Im using a service ;) anyway i found a solution, Thanks!